# How can i show my plan message in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I read this link for alert message:
http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

I want use that message box for my asp.net project,how can i use that link in my asp.net project?for example i have one asp.net button on my project and i want when user press that button ,show the up link message to user.thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? You can call it from your JavaScript code.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi thanks my friend to pay attention to my problem i want call the asp.net behind code

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi. There is no such thing as code behind in asp.net-mvc (pay attention to your tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call javascript from code behind, assuming that you are using c# as the code behind, just write this code where you want to show the message:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "thanks msg", "alert('Thanks');", true);
```

you can replace `alert('Thanks');` with your jquery or javascript code.